# Angular momentum about an axis other than axis of rotation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I know the formula for angular momentum about the axis of rotation i.e, $L = I\omega$. But what if I need to calculate the angular momentum about some axis other than the axis of rotation. Is it going to be the same as $L$ about rotational axis or is it a different value?

Comment: *I know the formula for angular momentum about the axis of rotation i.e, L=Iω*. What do you mean by *some axis other than the axis of rotation*? If you take any point on a rigid body and measure [the angular velocity about that point it will always be the same as any other point on the body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248612/velocity-of-the-points-of-a-rigid-body/248621#248621).

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum of a body about some axis other than its axis of rotation is the angular momentum of its center of mass:
$$\vec L=\vec R\times M\vec V,$$
where $\vec R$ and $\vec V$ are the position and velocity of the center of mass respectively.

Well, it is a general theorem from mechanics that the total angular momentum about *any* axis for a system of particles is given by:
$$\vec L=\vec R\times M\vec V+I\vec \omega,$$
Where the first term is the angular momentum of the system's center of mass and the second term is the systems angular momentum from it's rotation about the center of mass or some other point. So neglecting the angular momentum about the center of mass one arrives at the expression for the angular momentum of the system about an arbitrary axis.

As an example, let us consider the angular momentum of a disc of uniform mass, about an axis through it's rim, where the disc is rotating about it's center. Taking as our coordinates an origin conincident with the axis passing through the disc's rim, we have that the total angular momentum of the disc is given as:
$$\vec L=\vec R\times M\vec V+I\omega\mathbf{\hat z}.$$ However, since the center of mass has no motion with respect to the axis through the disc's rim, $\vec V=0$, so that:
$$\vec L=I\omega\mathbf{\hat z}.$$ Which is the angular momentum of the disc's axis of rotation, viz. the axis passing through it's center.

Comment: Can u please explain how did you get this

Comment: @yyzr Ok. Gave an explanation in the edited post.

Comment: Why are you neglecting the angular momentum about the com?

Comment: @yyzr Well if you want the *total* angular momentum, you should not neglect it. If you want *only* the angular momentum about the axis other than that of the axis of rotation then you should neglect it.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating angular momentum about a point that passes outside the body , the angular momentum can be calculated by the formula :-

Angular momentum about a point A = $L_A$

$L_A$ = $MV_{CM}R$ + $I_{CM}W$ where $V_{CM}$ is the velocity of the centre of mass of the rigid body and $I_{CM}$ is the moment of inertia of the body about the axis of rotation passing through the centre of mass ,and r is the **perpendicular distance of the point A from the line of action of velocity vector of centre of mass**. This is also true for calculating angular momentum about any moving point A,

$L_{CM}$ = $I_{CM}W$ is valid for calculating the angular monentum about the centre of mass (even if it is moving).

$L$ = $MVR$ is true for point like masses.

$L_P$ = $I_{P}W$ where P is a stationary point **lying on the rigid body.**

**Do keep in mind the sign conventions while solving for angular momentum!**

Comment: All of these formulas are for calculating $L$ about the axis of rotation except the first one. I was asking how to calculate $L$ about an axis about which the body doesn't rotate. Using the first equation you have written and assuming velocity of COM zero I get $L=I\omega$

Comment: "About an axis about which the body doesnt rotate"- Do you mean , like the case for rolling without slipping?

Comment: I mean, like let a disc is rotating about an axis passing through its centre, but I want calculate angular momentum about an axis passing through its rim

Comment: @yyzr The angular momentum of a disc in the case which you describe is equal to its angular momentum about it's center of rotation, i.e. the center of mass has no motion about an axis pass through it's rim, therefore its angular momentum is purely rotational. An object only has angular momentum from an axis about which it rotates and angular momentum of it's center of mass about the origin of coordinates.